# "Could not find the channel where this message came from in the cache!" when attempting to edit or delete a DM message

Tags: discord.js, bots

I am trying to edit a message that was sent in a DM. Here is the code that does this:

```js
async execute(interaction){

//function...
//member and gameData are defined

//remove the message containing the buttons and send a new one
//build new embed
const gmEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle(`Approved Join Request`)
    .setDescription(`${member.user.tag} has successfully joined ${gameData.gameName}.`)
    .setColor(0x33ff88);
try {
    await interaction.message.edit({ embeds: [gmEmbed] });
}
catch (e) {
    console.log(`[WARN] Unable to edit a DM to ${interaction.user.tag} accepting a player:\n${e}`);
}

//rest of function...

}
```

And this is what happens when the interaction is created and this function is run:

> [WARN] Unable to followup a DM to username redacted accepting a player:
> Error [ChannelNotCached]: Could not find the channel where this message came from in the cache!

In index.js I have the client logging in with `const client = new Client({ intents: [..., GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages] });` but I'm not sure if that's relevant to this issue.

How can I edit a message in a DM?

Edit 1: `interaction.message.fetch().then(message => message.edit(...))` doesn't work. `interaction.channel` returns `null`. I believe the gateway intent should allow this, but it doesn't seem to. Also, strangely it seems to work sometimes, seemingly the first time the function is called for that interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `interaction.editReply()` to edit the reply to an interaction.

```js
// ...
try {
   await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [gmEmbed] });
} catch (e) {
   console.log(`[WARN] Unable to edit a DM to ${interaction.user.tag} accepting a player:\n${e}`);
}
```

Comment: `interaction` is an interaction created by a button press. I am trying to edit the message attached to that button. So `interaction.editReply()` would not work.